# Sharepoint Calendar sync with Google Calendar

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, google-calendar-api

I've setup Sharepoint Foundation 2010 on a Windows Server 2008 R2 recently. It will be used by our office for collaboration. We'll be using SharedDocuments, Tasks and Calendar.

I'm a heavy user of Google calendar and I'm using Android phone. Thus I would like sync all the calendar items and if possible tasks from Sharepoint to my google automatically, so that I can see my work schedule from my phone.

If there's no ready product, and not to complex to develop one, I wouldn't mind to do so. I'm a .Net developer.

Thank you

Comment: actually, a lot of people asked me this question and i have to say that there's no built-in solution.. so i started a codeplex project :-) if you want to help out please feel free to email me

Comment: @Andreas - Sounds interesting. Always wanted to participate in some OSS, but haven't found a purpose, now there is.

Answer (score 3):

There is no built in solution, but development shouldn't be that hard with all the tutorials available:

- [SharePoint To Google Calendar SynchronizationSharePoint To Google Calendar Synchronization](http://blog.bendsoft.com/2011/04/sharepoint-to-google-calendar-synchronization/)
- [WebApps Post: Sync Outlook Calendar with Sharepoint Calendar and Google Calendar](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/7810/sync-outlook-calendar-with-sharepoint-calendar-and-google-calendar)

and if you're looking for a paid solution: [RSSBus](http://Keep%20Your%20SharePoint%20Calendar%20Synced%20with%20Google) is the way to go.

In the end you could easily use the generated RSS from the Sharepoint calendar to sync it to the iCal format.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I believe you meant development  shouldn't be that hard

Answer (score 0):

Why sync? that is soo 2005 ;)

What you could do is to add a loayer to your android calendar. Heck, you van do this in outlook as well!
The hardest part is when you want to display another calendar along with one INSIDE sharepoint; see link below where they seem to have found the right answer.
http://weblogs.asp.net/sharadkumar/archive/2010/03/12/aggregate-sharepoint-event-items-into-your-calendar-view-using-calendar-overlay.aspx