# Synchronize Sharepoint Calendar with Google Calendar

Tags: sharepoint-2010

How to Synchronize SharePoint 2010 Calendar with Google Calendar except outlook ?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in this post [Sharepoint Calendar sync with Google Calendar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7382897/sharepoint-calendar-sync-with-google-calendar)
. Sharepoint provides no built in feature, which allows you to Sync with Google Calendar.